# Get rising edge using diode

Tags: diodes, schematics

Here is circuit from Horowitz's "Art of electronics" book:
[image]

The problem is that I can't get expected signal from R2 resistor in OrCAD:
[image]
Here is diode pass both rising and falling edges.Why?

**EDIT**:
Here is correct settings of voltage source:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried lowering the value of R27 to 100 ohms ? It now appears to behave as a capacitive voltage divider. Maybe also increase rise and fall time of V25 to 1us.

Comment: After increasing rise and fall time to 1us I saw correct output. Thank you! Can you explain me why this matters?

Comment: Did you have a look at your diodes datasheet, its capacitance and switching times leakage etc.?

Comment: Explanation: when the rise/fall time of the source is 1 ns it contains only high frequency components, these couple directly to the output because the diode also has some capacitance. When you increase the rise/fall time there will be more low frequency components in the signal which are needed to show the diode behaviour. The diode is just a bit too slow for a 1 ns rise/fall time signal.

Comment: What is the typical Rising/Falling edge time of the MCU's like AVR and STM32? Which will be output signal on R2 if I will use, for example, PWM of stm32 as input signal?

Comment: Read about "reverse recovery time" of diodes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, parasitics.

A parasitic model of a diode unfortunately contains a capacitive component.
The art of electronics was describing what would occur with ideal components. SPICE attempts to model actual components.

[image]

A 1n5817 has a total capacitance of 110pF

[image]

If the circuit is simulated with an IDEAL diode (with a 10V pulse with 1ns risetime) the resultant waveform is:

[image]

If a capacitor is placed in parallel with the diode:

[image]

The waveform that is produced is in line with your simulation

[image]

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you! I used DBREAK element from BREAKOUT library as ideal diode and get similar result. Does it correct way?